Pytorch Conv1d on simple 1d for Signal: The size of tensor a (100) must match the size of tensor b (16)
I am learning Pytorch using signal classification where all values are binary (0 or 1). The input data is a vector of [ ,32] and the output is [ ,16]. I have a large dataset of more than 400K samples. This is the dataset: LINK
I want to build a CNN model to predict Y from X. I am always obtain this error :
> RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (100) must match the size of tensor b (16) at non-singleton dimension 1

There is only 1 dimension on all my work. This is the code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F  # Import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

# Load data
LinkOfDataset = 'NewNew.csv'
Data = pd.read_csv(LinkOfDataset, encoding='utf-8')

ChallengeLen = 32
ResponseLen = 16

NumberOfTraining = 0.6
NumberOfValidation = 0.2
NumberOfTesting = 0.2

# Split data
TrainData, TestData = train_test_split(Data, train_size=0.8)
TestData, ValidationData = train_test_split(TestData, train_size=0.8)

XTrainData = TrainData.iloc[:, :ChallengeLen].values
YTrainData = TrainData.iloc[:, ChallengeLen:].values

XValidationData = ValidationData.iloc[:, :ChallengeLen].values
YValidationData = ValidationData.iloc[:, ChallengeLen:].values

XTestData = TestData.iloc[:, :ChallengeLen].values
YTestData = TestData.iloc[:, ChallengeLen:].values

# Convert data to PyTorch tensors
XTrainTensor = torch.tensor(XTrainData, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
YTrainTensor = torch.tensor(YTrainData, dtype=torch.float32)

XValidationTensor = torch.tensor(XValidationData, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
YValidationTensor = torch.tensor(YValidationData, dtype=torch.float32)

XTestTensor = torch.tensor(XTestData, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
YTestTensor = torch.tensor(YTestData, dtype=torch.float32)

# Create dataloaders
train_dataset = TensorDataset(XTrainTensor, YTrainTensor)
validation_dataset = TensorDataset(XValidationTensor, YValidationTensor)
test_dataset = TensorDataset(XTestTensor, YTestTensor)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=100, shuffle=True)
validation_loader = DataLoader(validation_dataset, batch_size=100, shuffle=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=100, shuffle=False)

# Define the model
class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()

        # Calculate the size of the input to the first fully connected layer
        # Initial length: 32
        # After conv1 + pool: 32 / 2 = 16
        # After conv2 + pool: 16 / 2 = 8
        # After conv3 + pool: 8 / 2 = 4
        # After conv4 + pool: 4 / 2 = 2
        # Output channels of conv4: 128
        self.fc1_input_dim = 128 * 2  # 128 channels * 2 length

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.fc1_input_dim, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 16)  # Output length is 16

        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))  # After conv1 + pool: [batch_size, 32, 16]
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))  # After conv2 + pool: [batch_size, 64, 8]
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))  # After conv3 + pool: [batch_size, 64, 4]
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))  # After conv4 + pool: [batch_size, 128, 2]
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)  # Flatten: [batch_size, 128*2 = 256]
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))  # Fully connected layer: [batch_size, 128]
        x = self.fc2(x)  # Output layer: [batch_size, 16]
        return x

model = CNNModel()

# Define loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.MSELoss()  # or nn.CrossEntropyLoss() if you are dealing with classification
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training loop
num_epochs = 1
history = {'loss': [], 'val_loss': [], 'accuracy': [], 'val_accuracy': []}

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    for X_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(X_batch)
        loss = criterion(outputs, y_batch)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
    history['loss'].append(epoch_loss)
    
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X_batch, y_batch in validation_loader:
            outputs = model(X_batch)
            loss = criterion(outputs, y_batch)
            val_loss += loss.item()
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += y_batch.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == y_batch).sum().item()
    epoch_val_loss = val_loss / len(validation_loader)
    epoch_val_accuracy = correct / total
    history['val_loss'].append(epoch_val_loss)
    history['val_accuracy'].append(epoch_val_accuracy)
    
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}, Val Loss: {epoch_val_loss:.4f}, Val Accuracy: {epoch_val_accuracy:.4f}')

# Save the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "PAutoencoder.pth")

# Plotting the training and validation loss
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(history['accuracy'], label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(history['val_accuracy'], label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()

plt.show()

I don't understand how to solve this problem

could you provide print(X_batch.shape) and print(Y_batch.shape) after line for X_batch, y_batch in validation_loader:
